# Is there a github repo for swapping tokens on curve.fi in solidity?

Tags: solidity, curve

I'm trying to create a contract that will programatically exchange tokens on curve.fi but since their whole app is written in vyper I have no idea how.

Is there some kind of resource like a github repo where they show how to do it?

Thanks a lot!